# In React, when the time exactly decide to re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused about when react does decide to re-render.

```
function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});

  console.log(position);

  const handleMove = (e) => {
    const newPos = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
    setPosition(newPos);
    position.x = e.clientX;
    position.y = e.clientY;
    setPosition(position);
  };

  return (
    <div onPointerMove={e => {
      handleMove(e);
    }}>
      <h1>{position.x}</h1>
      <h1>{position.y}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code above is from my React component function.

In this code, you can see that I'm mutating the object used as state. Although it's a method forbidden by React, I wrote this code for experimental purposes.

After mutating the original object and then calling the setState function, re-rendering does not occur. To force a re-render, I created and assigned newPos, and then reassigned the original position object.

Upon logging, I noticed that my component function is continuously called, and the position's x and y values are consistently updated. I also confirmed that in the returned JSX object, position.x and position.y values are changing.

However, the actual webpage doesn't reflect these changes. What could be the reason? Is the re-rendering rejected during the process of comparing the existing DOM with the newly created DOM after the JSX is returned? But the values in the JSX have clearly changed.

Is there anyone who can provide a clear answer to this?

Comment: Can this have to do with the fact that `position` is an `object` and your `.x` and `.y` are just reading from the object, but when calling `setPosition` you are making it a new object, which means the old object is not updated. You should try `setPosition(Object.assign(position, newPosition))` to ensure your original reference object is updated so your JSX code still references the right object?

Comment: My point is, why doesn't React re-render even though the JSX has been changed and returned? I'm curious about at what point it got rejected, and why it was rejected. Isn't it supposed to re-render automatically when values change?

Comment: It wasn't - it is being re-rendered, your state object just isn't updated because there's no way react can actually tell JSX the object itself has changed to a different object. You should update the values in the object itself, then call the update for the object.

Comment: "*I created and assigned newPos, and then reassigned the original position object.*" - why? What were you trying to achieve by calling  `setPosition` twice? Just doing `setPosition(newPos);` would be enough, and should have worked.

Comment: See "I wrote this code for experimental purposes..."

Comment: @SoZettaSho the first call to `setPosition` works if used alone right? But the second call doesn’t work if used alone. If you combine both calls, then the new behavior is *” …that my component function is continuously called, and the position's x and y values are consistently updated. I also confirmed that in the returned JSX object, position.x and position.y values are changing.”*?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to understand this is as two separate behaviors that, taken separately, each make sense:

1. The state is being changed (by `setPosition(newPos)`), so React schedules a new call to render the component. That new call will see the latest state, after [batching](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates), including the current contents of the `position` object.

   - This seems legit, right? The state did in fact change, so why *shouldn't* React re-call the component function?
   - Of course, it might be *even better* if it were smart enough to skip rendering the component in this case (since by the time it calls it, the state has changed back), but there's nothing *wrong* with rendering.
2. But the state change ends up not actually happening (because `setPosition(position)` undoes the `setPosition(newPos)` — obviously React has never examined, let alone stored, the contents of `position`, so all it knows is that it's the same object); React detects that, and skips post-rendering steps: it doesn't recurse through the new and old results to see what's changed, it doesn't re-render any child components whose properties are changed, and as you've seen, it doesn't update the DOM.

   - This also seems legit, right? The state ends up the same, so why *should* React redo all of that work?
   - Of course, it would also be *OK* if React didn't have this optimization, and if it did all of its post-render steps even when it turns out there wasn't a state change; but, it's nice that it has this optimization.

Taken together, I agree that these behaviors seem strange — why bother re-calling the component function if it ends up not actually using the result? — but, of course, that's not how computers "think". The post-render steps have an "oh, wait, the state has changed back!" optimization, but they're not in the business of telling the render step how to do its job.

Note that the post-render steps are typically *much* more expensive than rendering itself, so the optimization is useful even in its current form; but it wouldn't surprise me at all if a future version of React incorporated the optimization that you were apparently expecting, where the render function is completely skipped in this case.

---

BTW, this bit:

```
    <div onPointerMove={e => {
      handleMove(e);
    }}>
```

specifies a new/different `pointerMove` handler on every render. In a real component where you're not just experimenting, you'd probably want to use [the `useCallback` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) to avoid causing unnecessary re-renders of child components and (worse yet) unnecessary DOM updates.

Comment: "*you'd probably want to use the useCallback hook*" - no, you'd just write `onPointerMove={handleMove}`

Comment: @Bergi: No, that wouldn't address the issue. (I mean, yes, it's clearer/simpler/better to write `onPointerMove={handleMove}`; but you'd still want to use `useCallback` in defining `handleMove` to begin with!)

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course

Answer (score 0):

[Objects in Javascript are a reference type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#comparing_objects). When you assign an object to a variable name, the value being assigned is a pointer, not a value. Quoting the MDN example:

```
// Two variables, two distinct objects with the same properties
const fruit = { name: "apple" };
const fruitbear = { name: "apple" };

fruit == fruitbear; // return false
fruit === fruitbear; // return false
```

The objects that `fruit` and `fruitbear` *point to* have the same value, but a comparison between the two variables show they are different because they point different memory locations. If you change a property of `fruit`, `fruitbear` will not change.

```
// Two variables, a single object
const fruit = { name: "apple" };
const fruitbear = fruit; // Assign fruit object reference to fruitbear

// Here fruit and fruitbear are pointing to same object
fruit == fruitbear; // return true
fruit === fruitbear; // return true

fruit.name = "grape";
console.log(fruitbear); // { name: "grape" }; not { name: "apple" }
```

This example shows that the value of `fruitbear` is a reference to the same object referenced by `fruit`, so changing properties of `fruit` will also change properties of `fruitbear`. This is why `setPosition(position)` will not trigger a re-render; the *value* of `position` is a pointer and that pointer does not change when properties of the object being referenced change. It *would* change if you created a new object and assign that to `position` before running `setPosition`.

This will always be the case when you use reference types like `Object` and `Array` with state. [The usual recommendation for react is to make state updates immutable](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state), which is what you did with `newPos`. As has been pointed out already the component will rerender if you `setPosition(newPos)`, but it will not rerender if you include the `setPosition(position)`.

So to answer your question... yes, React will try to batch changes in the virtual DOM to minimize the number of unnecessary DOM updates (for example if you set state to one value and then immediately set it to another value in response to the same event). But no, the values have not clearly changed, because in your example the value in state is the same before and after the pointer move event.

Comment: Clear answer for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already understands this; or at least, this doesn't engage with the difficult part of the question, which is why React is re-calling the render function but discarding the returned JSX.

Comment: We'd have to hear from OP themselves if they need clarification. OP seems to understand that they need to update state to trigger an update. I assume that their misunderstanding has to do with their statement "But the values in the JSX have clearly changed" and my answer addresses why React would judge that the state value has not changed at the time when it runs its diff algorithm. OP, is the real issue that you think JSX is the same as DOM?